# Obtain value preceding maximum value

Tags: sql, max

For example, given this table of sparse ids:

```
|id|
| 1|
| 2|
| 3|
| 6|
| 7|
```

I can obtain the highest "id" from my table using this query:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM Comics
```

I get:

```
|id|
| 7|
```

How can I get the "id" just preceding the highest "id" (even if the values aren't continuous)?

Comment: ORDER BY id DESC and pick up the second one in your program. BTW, what's your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT max(id) FROM Comics
```

is the same as

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM Comics ORDER BY ID DESC
```

note: this is transact sql syntax, use rownum or limit depending on your vendor

to get row 2 you can do

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 2 id 
     FROM Comics 
     ORDER BY ID DESC) 
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: I didnt know you can have SQL inside SQL like that, thank you.

Comment: @Joseph this technique is known as a derived table or an inline view.

Comment: If your using mysql or postgre the query is much simpler just use the offest functionality

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, you could first find the maximum id (which you've done), then find the maximum id that is *less than* (`<`) the maximum.

Specifically,

```
select max(id) from Comics where id < 7
```

Alternately, you can order the results in descending order:

```
select id from Comics order by id desc
```

and then look at the *second* row returned.

Comment: or sort in descending order use `OFFSET` to skip to the second row and `LIMIT` to return just the 1.

Answer (score 0):

this would do it as well ..

```
SELECT
    max(id)
FROM
    Comics 
WHERE id < (SELECT max(id) FROM Comics)
```