# How to find n'th highest value of a column?

Tags: mysql

Is there a command akin to:

- `2nd highest salary from tbl_salary` or
- `4th highest salary from tbl_salary` ?

I've seen:

```
select salary
from tbl_salary t
where &n = (
    select count(salary) 
    from(
        select distinct salary
        from tbl_salary
    )where t.salary<=salary
);
```

How does this it works?

Are there other simple ways to get result?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80706

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255964/obtain-value-preceding-maximum-value

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's a basic query, then just use LIMIT:

```
-- get the 4th highest salary
SELECT salary FROM tbl_salary
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 3,1
```

Comment: and if if it is not basic query then?

Comment: well if it's not a derived field or anything (eg: I want to find the user record of the person who has posted the 5th most articles) this method will work fine. After that, it's probably just a case of using a subquery.

Comment: @nickf, I'm getting 5th highest by executing the above query! `limit 3,1` will get 4th highest, am I right? Please advise

Comment: @arun, `limit 0,1` is first result. So yes `limit 3,1` is 4th.

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from employee order by salary desc limit 1,1
```

Description : `limit x,y`

- x: The row offset from which you want to start displaying records. For nth record it will be n-1.
- y: The number of records you want to display. (Always 1 in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but there's no point in answering a 2.5 year old question which has also an accepted answer.

Comment: @tombom syntax explanation

Answer (score 6):

// for highest salary of table

```
select salary from table order by salary desc limit 0,1
```

// for second highest salary

```
select salary from table order by salary desc limit 1,1
```

Using this query you get nth number of salary from table....

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple way to get the result of n'th highest value

put n=2 to get second highest salary
pur n=4 to get fourth highest salary
and so on...

Here is query
if n=2

```
select salary from tbl_salary e1
where 2 = (
select distinct(count(salary))
from tbl_salary e2
where e1.salary< e2.salary
)
```

Best luck

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the limit clause:

```
select * from tbl_salary order by salary desc limit 2,1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but:

SELECT salary FROM tbl_salary ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT n,1

Where n is the position you want - 1 (i.e. to get the second highest salary it would be LIMIT 1,1)

Comment: by using keyword `DISTINCT` will give accurate answer...m i right?

Comment: @I Like PHP: If your table contains duplicate salaries, yes. Or you could use GROUP BY salary

Answer (score 2):

SELECT sal from emp order by sal desc limit 1,1

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Implementation,

```
 (select * from tbl_salary order by salary desc limit 5) order by salary limit 1;


 (select * from tbl_salary order by salary desc limit 2) order by salary limit 1;
```